# How to fill text with image and make what can't fit appear transparent?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

[image]

The Draw Inside feature will fill up the text with image. However, how do you make what can't fit look transparent as in the image above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to do in Photoshop.

You need two copies of the image layer, and a white background.

Set the the top layer as a clipping mask over the Y text.

Then use the Pen tool to create a vector mask to mask out the bottom layer, then set this layer to a lower opacity so the white shows through.

Something like this:

[image: Example image showing arrangement of layers and masks]

You can download the PSD file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/ylogo) if you want to examine the file.

Comment: Pretty much same thing for illustrator as well

Comment: Thank you. I have created a replica using your mechanism. One more question, when I create a vector mask, the default background colour of it is white, at least in my case. Is there any shortcut to creating a grey background for a vector mask? thanks

Comment: @Hooey Not sure what you mean. The vector mask should have no background - if it is just a mask. Do you perhaps mean you have the "Shape" option in the Pen tool checked? If so, change it to "Path".

Comment: @Hooey and Billy Kerr... Sounds like maybe he wants the vector mask to be the inverted? To invert the vector mask: Click on the mask thumbnail in the Layers Panel, press the 'A' key (Path Selection Tool; black arrow) and select your path. Then go to the Path Operations button at the top of the UI and click on 'Combine Shapes'.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate the image layer.

Add a mask to the layer.

Reduce opacity.

Comment: can you tell me more about adding a mask to which layer? do I create another layer? Sorry I am quite new with Illustrator